# Characters do not render properly when fetched from database

Tags: flutter, dart

When I pull data from my database (UTF8 table), special characters do not render as they should when displayed in the app. For example, the screenshot below shows a distorted ' sign (in the first line, "Realship Corporation[BAD RENDER]s fleet..."

Is there something I should be doing differently?

[image: Distorded sign]

Using a simple

```
   final response = await http.get(helpers.helperConnectionString +
        'GetDiscountsAndDealsForCategory?token=$_token&categoryid=$_currentCategory&secureKey=${helpers.helperSecureKey}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List data = json.decode(response.body);
}
```

and then showing it by simply using

```
Text(data[i]['CompanyDescription'].toString())
```

Comment: Please include the code which shows how you are getting data from the database (also... what type of database?). Right now, we can only guess what you are doing which is not meaningful. Also, please split up your problem into separate questions.

Comment: Added code sample, as requested.

Comment: It looks like your API endpoint are not specifying a charset on the result or does report the wrong charset. Can you verify that your endpoint are returning UTF-8 and HTTP header specify the content as UTF-8?

Comment: So the data is saved in DB without issue, but when I return it using my ASMX service as JSON it renders it wrong.

Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_payload));

This is what Im using with NewtonSoft, can't see any way of setting an encoding?

Comment: Hm is I do this, it gives the correct results...

var xxx = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_payload);

So something with the Context.Response.Write that is acting up?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So simply setting this flag before the write seems to fix it:

```
 Context.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
```

So the full code turns out to be:

```
 Context.Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
 Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_payload));
```